# Сортировка на python

Tags: python

Изучаю `python`. Наткнулся на такой пример в книге по алгоритмам:

```
def find_Smallest(arr):
    smallest = arr[0]
    smallest_index = 0
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] < smallest:
            smallest = arr[i]
            smallest_index = i
    return smallest_index
```

Здесь меня смущает один момент: Почему пишется `smallest = arr[i]`, а не `arr[i] = smallest`. Мне говорили, что это разные вещи, но как понимать когда и как писать? Я понимаю, что зависит от задачи, просто я новичок, не судите строго.

Comment: Прежде чем читать книгу по алгоритмам, вы прочитали книгу по языку?

Comment: Переменной слева присваивается значение справа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор `=` выполняет присваивание значения некоторой переменной. То есть, грубо говоря, слева от "равно" у вас та коробочка, в которую нужно положить значение, а справа от "равно" - значение, которое нужно положить.

Этот код берёт значение из i-го элемента списка `arr`, и записывает его в переменную `smallest`:

```
smallest = arr[i]
```

А этот - наоборот, берёт значение из `smallest`, и помещает его в i-й элемент списка `arr`:

```
arr[i] = smallest
```

Answer (score 3):

Это алгоритм по поиску минимального элемента в массиве, а не сортировка.

Вы обходите массив и, если выполняется условие `arr[i] < smallest`, присваиваете переменной `smallest` значение `arr[i]`. Таким образом, после обхода всего массива, вернётся минимальный его элемент.